# C++ Convert stringstream into ifstream?

Tags: c++, ifstream, stringstream

I am working with two pieces of code,

The first class uses an AAssetManager (Android NDK object) to read an "asset" and save it's contents to a single string. It then turns the string into a stringstream and parses it.

The second class parses type ifstream, which must be associated with a file.

Is there some way I can convert a string or stringstream into an ifstream so I don't have to change the entirety of one of these classes?

Comment: You could make all the ifstreams into istreams. Otherwise store to a file then reopen.

Comment: The parser class should use `istream` not `ifstream`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can turn the `ifstream` into an `istream`. An `ifstream` is simply a more specific form of an `istream`. A `stringstream` inherits from an `istream`, so you can just pass the `stringstream` directly. If this is not available to you, then you would store the string to a file, then reopen the file with an `ifstream`, and pass that `ifstream` to the second function.